# How do I fix laggy/choppy scrolling through images with Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3, angular5

when i sroll down image loaded but when i scroll up image laggy

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let image of imageList">

    <img [src]="image"/>

    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        Nine Inch Nails Live
      </ion-card-title>
      <p>
        The most popular industrial group ever, and largely responsible for bringing the music to a mass audience.
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

[image]

thanks for reading my question !

Comment: You can optimise images to make them as small and friendly as possible without trading off too much quality, consider the target screen size and bring the resolution of the images down a little to suit. You can also run them through something like this https://tinypng.com/ to bring the size down a bit more. If your list is very large consider using virtualscroll - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/. To disguise the pop in you can also consider a skeleton screen https://css-tricks.com/building-skeleton-screens-css-custom-properties/ I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answers . I don't know why the images above is loaded but when i scroll up appears white overlay